# 16.04 to 17.10 login loop because of xsession and upstart

Tags: 17.10, upstart

long story short, I upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10, and when I try to login I get a black screen for a second then I'm back to the login screen again. After inspecting .xsession-errors I found this line

`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99x11-common_start: line 5: /sbin/upstart: No such file or directory`

The referenced file has only one line - except for the comments

`exec $STARTUP`

but there's another file in the same directory named 99upstart that has this line

`STARTUP="/sbin/upstart --user`

I tried searching how to fix this, but all I could find is that systemd is replacing upstart, with no way mentioned of how to fix this

Comment: How exactly did you 'upgrade' from 16.04 to 17.10? That is not a supported path. We usually recommend a clean install to prevent precisely this kind of problem.

Comment: as mentioned in [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes)

* Open the "Software & Updates" Setting in System Settings.

* Select the 3rd Tab called "Updates".

* Set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version".

* Press Alt+F2 and type in "update-manager -c" (without the quotes) into the command box

* Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '17.04' is available

* If not you can also use "/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk"

* Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions

Comment: I have the same issue, and it is very hard for a basic linux user to understand what must be fixed. Everyone is saying 16.04 to 17.10 ugrade is not supported...  The worst part is I've just followed the popup telling me a new version is available and clicked on upgrade now !

Comment: Same here after upgrading when suggested by the Software Updater dialog!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just move or remove upstart files from Xsession.d to get it running. In my case, 
00upstart, 99upstart, 99x11-common_start needed to be moved.

Comment: This may work but the `apt purge upstart` solution is the proper one.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt purge upstart
```

fixed that problem for me.

Upstart is replaced by systemd in 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with

```
sudo apt remove --purge upstart
```